Run-time error '9' for Yahoo Finance data extract
My VBA code to extract stock price data from Yahoo Finance now shows an error.
The bug is at the following line ReDim resultArray(0 To UBound(csv_rows), 0 To nColumns) As Variant
Is this due to Yahoo changing its website structure? How should I edit my code to continue extracting data from Yahoo Finance?
Sub getYahooFinanceData(tickerSymbol As String, startDate As String, endDate As String, frequency As String, _
cookie As String, crumb As String, ByVal ticker As Long)
    Dim resultFromYahoo As String
    Dim objRequest
    Dim csv_rows() As String
    Dim resultArray As Variant
    Dim nColumns As Integer
    Dim iRows As Integer
    Dim CSV_Fields As Variant
    Dim iCols As Integer
    Dim tickerURL As String

    'Construct URL
    '***************************************************
    tickerURL = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/" & tickerSymbol & _
        "?period1=" & startDate & _
        "&period2=" & endDate & _
        "&interval=" & frequency & "&events=history" & "&crumb=" & crumb
    'Sheets("Parameters").Range("K" & ticker - 1) = tickerURL
    '***************************************************
               
    'Get data from Yahoo
    '***************************************************
    Set objRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    With objRequest
        .Open "GET", tickerURL, False
        '.setRequestHeader "Cookie", cookie
        .send
        .waitForResponse
        resultFromYahoo = .ResponseText
    End With
    '***************************************************
        
    'Parse returned string into an array
    '***************************************************
    nColumns = 6 'number of columns minus 1  (date, open, high, low, close, adj close, volume)
    csv_rows() = Split(resultFromYahoo, Chr(10))
    csv_rows = Filter(csv_rows, csv_rows(0), False)
    ReDim resultArray(0 To UBound(csv_rows), 0 To nColumns) As Variant
     
    For iRows = LBound(csv_rows) To UBound(csv_rows)
        CSV_Fields = Split(csv_rows(iRows), ",")
        If UBound(CSV_Fields) > nColumns Then
            nColumns = UBound(CSV_Fields)
            ReDim Preserve resultArray(0 To UBound(csv_rows), 0 To nColumns) As Variant
        End If
    
        For iCols = LBound(CSV_Fields) To UBound(CSV_Fields)
            If IsNumeric(CSV_Fields(iCols)) Then
                resultArray(iRows, iCols) = Val(CSV_Fields(iCols))
            ElseIf IsDate(CSV_Fields(iCols)) Then
                resultArray(iRows, iCols) = CDate(CSV_Fields(iCols))
            Else
                resultArray(iRows, iCols) = CStr(CSV_Fields(iCols))
            End If
        Next
    Next


Drop the As Variant   When it fails what is the value of UBound(csv_rows) ?

@TimWilliams UBound(csv_rows) has a value of -1

Debug.Print resultFromYahoo and see if it's what you expect.

See: https://www.reddit.com/r/sheets/comments/1farvxr/broken_yahoo_finance_url/

I noticed on 9/7/2024 that Yahoo Finance no longer provides free downloads (spreadsheet format).  That option requires a $50/month subscription. So our scripts don't work.  We can still get the data in HTML form, but i haven't figured out how to parse that yet.  Perhaps someone here has...

This looks like it should go into a comment, as it doesn't include a concrete solution
